# How to add add custom assets into .apk file?

Tags: android, qt, qt-creator, qmake

I need to have some files in android assets folder, how can I add them using QtCreator/QMake?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have the following structure in your source directory:

```
foo.pro
extra_data/file1
extra_data/file2
…
```

Adding the following to foo.pro should deploy the extra_data folder to assets://extra_data (exact path might differ, cannot verify right now) in the APK:

```
folder_01.source = extra_data
folder_01.target = extra_data
DEPLOYMENTFOLDERS += folder_01
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, tried this, but it doesn't work :( please note that I'm using Qt 5.2

Comment: Actually it does work. Doublecheck ;)
This is the way qml files copied by QtCreator itself.

Comment: Worked, thank you. However, it seems that these blocks can't appear in conditional blocks, strange...

Comment: What is folder_01?

Comment: @Heidi just a self-chosen identifier

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Do not work on Qt5.9.1, I build(without deploy) the app with and without deployment, the size of the output folder remain the same(extra_data is bigger than 20MB).

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing the application, then simply copy/paste the files in assets folder.

But if your application is already built and available as **.apk** file then you cannot modify any of its content.

Comment: I'm developing application using Qt 5.2
the question is how to make it by Qmake

Answer (score 0):

Copying files to /5.2.0/android_armv7/src/android/java/assets did the trick

Comment: Where is that path relative from?